# Can't take 'get' argument in a bootstrap form without submit button

Tags: javascript, html, django, twitter-bootstrap

I am making a form without submit button using bootstrap, javascript, python and django.
My form consists of radio button group only.

There is code like this.

in html:

```
<html>
<body>
<form id="sort_form" method="get" role="form" action="{% url "home" %}">
<div class="btn-group" data-toggle="buttons">
<div class="btn btn-primary">
<input id="input_agree" name="how_to_sort" value="agree" type="radio">{% trans "Agree" %}
</div>
<div class="btn btn-primary">
<input id="input_recently" name="how_to_sort" value="recently" type="radio">{% trans "recently" %}
</div>
<div class="btn btn-primary">
<input id="input_more_comments" name="how_to_sort" value="more_comments" type="radio">{% trans "more comments" %}
</div>
</div>
</form>
<script type="text/javascript" src="{% static "js/main_page.js" %}">
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Because of non-submit button, i add a simple javascript like this.

in main_page.js

```
document.getElementById("input_more_comments").onclick = function() {
  document.getElementById("sort_form").submit();
};
document.getElementById("input_agree").onclick = function() {
  document.getElementById("sort_form").submit();
};
document.getElementById("input_recently").onclick = function() {
  document.getElementById("sort_form").submit();
};
```

But, i don't have any parameters in 'GET' request. What's wrong? i don't have any idea.
Any help, plz.
Thank u so much for ur help previously!!!

Comment: Are you sure the form is submitted first? The `onclick` should be on inputs and not on the form itself (to submit the form, indeed).

Comment: @MaximeLorant Thanks a lot. i made a silly mistake. i edit my code  like above code. But it doesn't still work. Do u know why?

Comment: If the view is called, try to `print(request.GET)`, maybe you are calling the wrong view. Also look with a web debugger if the JS code is really executed.

Comment: Thanks for your help. i have tried the same thing in a normal form. It does work correctly. But in a bootstrap-type input, doesn't work. i guess problem is related to bootstrap js code. However, i'm a novice in javascript. I should learn to debug javascript. Thank you so much :)

Answer (score 0):

The onclick has to be on some input button and not on the form itself.
You can try the following:

```
document.getElementById("#sort_form input").onclick = function() {
     document.getElementById("#sort_form").submit();
};
```

Another way could be to change your input look like this:

```
 <input name="sort_form_input" onclick="location.href='/url_to_submit/your_input_value" />;
```

Comment: Thank you so much. When I have tried your advice in a normal form without bootstrap, It does work. But in a bootstrap-form, doesn't work. At a guess, i should inspect bootstrap code. Might u know why?

Comment: It should just work, you need not inspect bootstrap code at all...you should focus on how your bootstrap form is different than the plain one which worked for you..